# Using boost::variant and getting a generic return type

Tags: c++, templates, boost-variant

I am looking for ideas of how to refactor this code or opinions on whether or not I'm over-thinking it. Consider the following `boost::variant`

```
using Pattern = boost::variant<std::regex, MyOwnClass>;
```

Now here is the idea of what I'd like to do:

```
Pattern pattern;

// do some stuff...

// see if the pattern matches some data
PatternVisitor pvisitor(dataBegin, dataEnd);
if (boost::apply_visitor(pvisitor, pattern))
{
    // want to use pvisitor.matches generically inside here 
    // regardless of what variant pattern is

    for (auto idx = 0; idx < pvisitor.matches.size(); idx)
    {
        // now use the match
        std::string strMatch(pvisitor.matches[idx].first, pvisitor.matches[idx].second);
        std::cout << strMatch << '\n';
    }
}
```

So, how to define `PatternVisitor`? I started with implementing the `std::regex` part and came up with something like:

```
struct PatternVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
    PatternVisitor(const char* sBegin, const char* sEnd)
        : searchBegin(sBegin), searchEnd(sEnd)
    {
    }

    bool operator()(const std::regex& regexp) 
    {
        return std::regex_search(searchBegin, searchEnd, regmatches, regexp, std::regex_constants::match_continuous);
    }

    bool operator()(const MyOwnClass& myClass)
    {
        // save this implementation for later, return true for now
        return true;
    }

    const char* searchBegin;
    const char* searchEnd;    
    std::cmatch matches;
};
```

Which was fine but... what about `MyOwnClass`? My first thought was that I could populate `std::cmatch` myself but that doesn't seem possible nor like a good idea. So, the current solution I have is something like this:

```
struct PatternVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
    PatternVisitor(const char* sBegin, const char* sEnd)
        : searchBegin(sBegin), searchEnd(sEnd)
    {
    }

    bool operator()(const std::regex& regexp) 
    {
        std::cmatch regmatches;
        if (std::regex_search(searchBegin, searchEnd, regmatches, regexp, std::regex_constants::match_continuous))
        {
            for (const auto& m : regmatches)
            {
                matches.push_back(std::make_pair(m.first, m.second));
            }
        }

        return !matches.empty();
    }

    bool operator()(const MyOwnClass& format)
    {
        // now I can just populate matches as needed
        return true;
    }

    const char* searchBegin;
    const char* searchEnd;    
    std::vector<std::pair<const char*, const char*>> matches;
};
```

While this works I do not like that I'm copying the data I need from `regmatches` into another vector.

What would be a good method to refactor this while being able to use the resulting matches in a generic way?

Answer (score 1):

You may apply your function inside the visitor, something like:

```
struct PatternVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
    PatternVisitor(const char* sBegin,
                   const char* sEnd,
                   std::function<void (const char*, const char*)> f)
        : searchBegin(sBegin), searchEnd(sEnd), f(f)
    {
    }

    bool operator()(const std::regex& regexp) 
    {
        std::cmatch regmatches;
        if (std::regex_search(searchBegin,
                              searchEnd,
                              regmatches,
                              regexp,
                              std::regex_constants::match_continuous)) {
            for (const auto& m : regmatches) {
                f(m.first, m.second);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool operator()(const MyOwnClass& myClass)
    {
        // save this implementation for later, return true for now
        return true;
    }

    const char* searchBegin;
    const char* searchEnd;    
    std::function<void (const char*, const char*)> f;
};
```

And then

```
Pattern pattern = /*...*/;
PatternVisitor pvisitor(dataBegin, dataEnd, [](const char* beg, const char* end)
    {
        std::string strMatch(beg, end);
        std::cout << strMatch << '\n';
    });
boost::apply_visitor(pvisitor, pattern);
```

Comment: Should have marked this sooner. This is what I ended up implementing.